# Can not merge data with another dataset

Tags: r

I have a  dataset that is like this: list

| df |
| --- |
| 200000 |
| 5666666 |

This dataset continues to 5551

Another dataset has also 5551 observations. I want to merge list dataset with another dataset. But no variable  is the same. Just row names are the same.

I gave that

```
merge(list,df,by="rownames")
```

The error message is that it should have a valid column name

I tried also merge_all but not work

It is not working? Could someone please help

Comment: What is ‘list’?

Comment: List is the name of the dataframe with only one column

Comment: The dataframe with the column df

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of ‘list’ then please. Also it’s a bad idea to call a data frame ‘list’ because ‘list’ is an inbuilt type in R.

Comment: Yes, i do it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to be more precise with the naming of your dataframe variables. I wouldn't use `list` but something like `df_description`. Either way, merging by rownames can be achieved by using `by = "row.names"` or `by = 0`. You can read more on `merge()` [in the documentation (under "Details")](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge).